# Sending emails through SMTP in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, smtp, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension that allows users to enter their smtp host, username, and password. In return, I will send a pre-defined message to a recipient based on the situation. Currently, I am looking at the emailjs package to use in my background.js file for sending the email. However, it does not support the in-reply-to header which I need. Does anyone have any suggestions for a package that can be used inside of a chrome extension that supports the in-reply-to header?